# Why don't my pygame sprites move about independently? And how do I make them move about independently?

Tags: python, pygame

With only 1 orchid sprite, it bounces around the screen more or less as I intend it to. When I add more, the orchid sprites move around together as a single mass and bounce off a boundary even though they don't come near to touching it. Here is the code:

```
#Import and Init
import pygame
import random
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

#Set Up the Window
width = 1240
height = 700
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Pollination!")

background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background = pygame.image.load("Forrest.jpg")
background = background.convert()

#Load and Convert the wasp
wasp = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
wasp.image = pygame.image.load("wasp1.gif")
wasp.rect = wasp.image.get_rect()
wasp_group = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle(wasp)

flowers = pygame.sprite.OrderedUpdates()

for i in range(5):
    orchid = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
    orchid.image = pygame.image.load("orchid1.gif")
    orchid.rect = orchid.image.get_rect()
    orchid.rect.right = random.randint(0, 1240)
    orchid.rect.top = random.randint(0, 700)
    flowers.add(orchid)

buzz = pygame.mixer.Sound("buzz.wav")
#Clock and Loop Variables
framerate = pygame.time.Clock()
GameGo = True

orchid_xinc = 2
orchid_yinc = 2

wasp_move = 5
#The Main Loop
while GameGo:

    #Tick the Clock
    framerate.tick(60)

    #Keyborad Keypress Events, Movement

    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_UP]:
        wasp.rect.top -= wasp_move
        if wasp.rect.top < -30:
            wasp.rect.top = -30
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_DOWN]:
        wasp.rect.top += wasp_move
        if wasp.rect.top > 625:
            wasp.rect.top = 625
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_LEFT]:
        wasp.rect.right -= wasp_move
        if wasp.rect.right < 110:
            wasp.rect.right = 110
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_RIGHT]:
        wasp.rect.right += wasp_move
        if wasp.rect.right > 1255:
            wasp.rect.right = 1255

    for orchid in flowers:
        if orchid.rect.top < -30:
            orchid_yinc *= -1
        if orchid.rect.top > 625:
            orchid_yinc *= -1
        if orchid.rect.right < 110:
            orchid_xinc *= -1
        if orchid.rect.right > 1255:
            orchid_xinc *= -1

        orchid.rect.right += orchid_xinc
        orchid.rect.top -= orchid_yinc

    for orchid in pygame.sprite.groupcollide(wasp_group, flowers, False, True):
        buzz.play()
##  #Blit our Images
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    flowers.draw(screen)
    wasp_group.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()


  #Handle a Close Event
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            GameGo = False

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I humbly suggest that you investigate the use of classes, really makes dealing with multiple identical but separate objects pretty easy.

Comment: I find it easier not to use classes, generally. Is it necessary in this case?

Comment: You're trying to control a group of identical sprites with a single set of global variables. It seems rather obvious to me that they're going to act identical as well. You're already using pygame's sprite class but in a pretty bare bones way, if you start making your own custom sprite classes you can easily handle so many more things and be completely independent of of every other object quite easily. Embrace OOP, there's a reason it's so popular.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps its the fact that you type "orchid_####" in your for loop that updates each orchid. If in your orchid class the **init** method defines a self.#### as it should, its called with "Object.####" and not an underscore. If i am wrong, check the "flowers.draw" function, making sure it draws all orchids using their own respective coordinates.

Comment: I changed the underscore to a period in the variables as you suggested, but this doesn't appear to solve my problem. In fact I get an error message now (AttributeError: 'Sprite' object has no attribute 'xinc') when I try more than one orchid.

Comment: Im sorry, revert those changes. I didn't see that you made the variable name orchid_xinc, and that it was an plain variable. Anyway, after reverting that, you should probably assign xinc and yincs to individual orchid, and have them be random. Right now xinc and yinc is the same for all of them, so of course they move in a group.